# UITableView reloadData when editing and keep animations

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I'm reloading a UITableView like this by overriding `-setEditing:animated` in my `UITableViewController` subclass when the user puts the table view into edit mode.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This works but is there a way to keep the animations?  Normally the red delete button and move button indicators slide into view.

I'm hiding section titles for empty sections but I want to show them when editing so the user can move a table view cell into an empty section which is why I'm doing a table reload when editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` instead.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    // specify appropriate sections you have.
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```